# Getting error as unfortunately stopped while navigating from one activity to another using image button

Tags: android

This is where i am getting the error as unfortunately stopped

```
    public void touch(View v)
    {
        Intent brd=new Intent(Selection.this,Broadband.class);
        startActivity(brd);
    }
    public void tu(View v)
    {
        Intent dtd=new Intent(Selection.this,Datacard.class);
        startActivity(dtd);
    }
```

where do i made a mistake pls correct it for further proceedings asps

Comment: try to add intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

Comment: where shld i add this

Comment: under each function uh ?

Comment: Intent dtd=new Intent(Selection.this,Datacard.class); dtd.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);  
startActivity(dtd);

Answer (score 0):

What error do you have? If those methods are in activity, just use

`new Intent(this, Broadband.class);` etc.